# Not getting Email Address from linkedin I can use jar file but emailaddress is null?

Tags: linkedin-api

```
accessToken=LinkedinDialog.oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(LinkedinDialog.liToken,verifier;
LinkedinDialog.factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);

client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);

Person profile = client.getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet.of(
                                        ProfileField.ID, ProfileField.FIRST_NAME,
                                        ProfileField.EMAIL_ADDRESS, ProfileField.LAST_NAME
                                        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't show this so I don't know if this is your issue or not, but access email address requires that you request the `r_emailaddress` member permission in your OAuth scope when you request your auth token.  Check your code and ensure you're asking for that permission.